# C evaluating a recursive sequence - expected expression error

Tags: c

I'm trying to code this recursive sequence for values up to n = 60. I know that x0 = 1.

Xn+1 = 2^(n+1) * (sqrt( 1 + 2^-n*Xn) - 1)

So far I have

```
int main ()
{
    // first term x0 = 1
    double xn = 1;
    double x;
    double squareRoot = 1 + (pow(2, -x) * xn);

    for (x = 1; x <= 60; x++)
    {
        double xn = pow(2, x) * double sqrt(squareRoot) - 1);
        printf("%f\n", xn);
    }

}
```

but I get expected expression error on the line where there is double sqrt.

Comment: missing parentheses.

Comment: What is `double` doing in `* double sqrt(...)`? How do you expect `squareRoot` be related to `x` in the loop, when it is evaluated outside the loop?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Isn't that the syntax of how you get the square root of a value in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, your code had syntax errors in this line:

```
double xn = pow(2, x) * double sqrt(squareRoot) - 1);
```

Here the parenthesis are not balanced as you have one more `)` than `(`. In addition you cannot place `double` as you did (it also is not needed as `sqrt` returns a `double`)

Below I placed code with comments of how I interpreted the equation along with notes on what I found ambiguous about how it was written:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    // You mentioned that x0 is 1.0 and so the variable which is updated is initialized as 1.0
    double x = 1.0;

    // Goal: Xn+1 = 2^(n+1) * (sqrt( 1 + 2^-n*Xn) - 1)
    // Notes:
    // - I named Xn as x to separate the updated variable from the iteration variable
    // - I interpreted "2^-n*Xn" as "pow(2.0, -n) * x" (rather than "pow(2.0, -n * x)")
    for (n = 1; n < 60; n++) {
        // Term A: 2^(n+1)
        double termA = pow(2.0, n + 1.0);

        // Term B: (sqrt( 1 + 2^-n*Xn) - 1)
        // Note that this involves the updated variable, it must be in the loop
        double termB = sqrt(1.0 + pow(2.0, -n) * x) - 1.0;

        // Update x: termA * termB
        x = termA * termB;
        printf("%f\n", x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Added for clarity**:

```
int main() {
    int n;

    double x = 1.0;
    for (n = 1; n < 60; n++) {
        // These are temporary values assigned every iteration
        // Note however that unlike your code "pow(2.0, -n) * x" is evaluated
        // every iteration and so it updates to reflect your desired equation
        // In your code you used "squareRoot" which did not update every iteration
        double termA = pow(2.0, n + 1.0);
        double termB = sqrt(1.0 + pow(2.0, -n) * x) - 1.0;

        // This updates the value of "x" every iteration
        // "x" corresponds to what you called "Xn" in your equation
        x = termA * termB;
        printf("%f\n", x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response, in my original code, I had xn = 1 initialized outside the loop and thus it was giving me the value 1 inside the loop every time. For yours, you had x = 1.0 outside but how come the x value inside the for loop is different every time?

Comment: In your code you had a variable named `squareRoot`  which was assigned before the loop and it was never assigned again during the loop. That does not reflect your desired equation as "sqrt( 1 + 2^-n*Xn)" must be updated every iteration of the loop

Comment: ^ haha that was kind of confusing, but I guess I'm asking how do you know when you have updated a variable outside a loop?

Comment: In your code you assign: `xn` as `xn = 1;` and `squareRoot` as `squareRoot = 1 + (pow(2, -x) * xn);`. This happens before the loop. Inside of the loop you never assign `squareRoot` and so it has the same value every iteration

Comment: @jqdc2224, I updated the answer to explain why my code reflects the desired behavior of your equation

Comment: I reread this just today and wanted to thank you again for how helpful this was

Answer (score 2):

**1.** A extra bracket here .

```
double xn = pow(2, x) * double sqrt(squareRoot) - 1);
```

And you don't need to mention type here -`double sqrt(squareRoot)` . You can write like this -

```
double xn = pow(2, x) * (sqrt(squareRoot) - 1);
```

**2.** Also this statement will create problem -

```
double x;
double squareRoot = 1 + (pow(2, -x) * xn);    //this statement

for (x = 1; x <= 60; x++)
```

Here you use `x` in `pow`  but it is outside loop and `x` is not initialized until loop. So you need to initialize `x` before this statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
double xn = pow(2, x) * double sqrt(squareRoot) - 1);
//                      ^^^^^^                     ^
//                      delete                 unbalanced
```

There are other logic errors as well, but I'll leave them for you to find and solve.

Comment: "There are other logic errors as well, but I'll leave them for you to find and solve"... Why wouldn't you just point them out? Seems pretty clear the OP is still learning

Comment: @asimes I figured out that the xn declared outside the loop is causing problems because it's always setting that value to 1. Is there any way to get xn to be last value iterated in the loop?